# function with the same name in kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Which function will be called ？

cscope：

```
[1] include/linux/sched.h 
Cscope tag: show_regs

1    108  /data/linux-3.4.7/arch/x86/kernel/process.c <<show_regs>>
         void show_regs(struct pt_regs *regs)
2     14  /data/linux-3.4.7/arch/x86/um/sysrq_32.c <<show_regs>>
         void show_regs(struct pt_regs *regs)
3     37  /data/linux-3.4.7/arch/x86/um/sysrq_64.c <<show_regs>>
         void show_regs(struct pt_regs *regs)
```

And how gcc know which function will be linked？

Comment: Are they all getting built into your kernel?  Looks like one is a 32-bit version and the other one 64-bit, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Within a shared library, a call to a function that is a global symbol costs a “call” instruction to a code location in the so-called PLT (procedure linkage table) which contains a “jump” instruction to the actual function's code.

when the language allows different entities to be named with the same identifier as long as they occupy a different namespace (where a namespace is typically defined by a module, class, or explicit namespace directive) collisions are resolved through the concept of name mangling.

Name mangling provides a way of encoding additional information in the name of a function, structure, class or another datatype in order to pass more semantic information from the compilers to linkers.

SRC : Wiki , gnu.org